# chroot SFTP user can't modify any files in mounted drive

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions, sftp, chroot

Well, here are the steps I’ve done; the problem is listed at the bottom.

```
sudo mkdir /home/test
sudo useradd test
sudo chown root:test /home/test
sudo chmod 755 /home/test
sudo groupadd testgroup
sudo useradd -G testgroup test
sudo useradd -G testgroup other
```

Then I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added the following to the end, so the user will only be able to view their home directory

```
Match group testgroup
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

then I restarted SSH (`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`)

After this I wanted to have this user be able to edit some other files in another user's home directory, so I used this command to mount it and give it permissions.

```
sudo mount -o bind /home/other/share /home/test/share
sudo chgrp -R testgroup /home/test/share
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /home/test/share
```

The share directory is owned by other, but the group is testgroup (users test & other). (Octal rwxrwxr-x  0775)

But my problem is that the test user can't modify any files in the share directory (/home/test/share)

Thanks,

---

Edit: output from some commands (logged in as `test` user):

> **`id –a`**
>    `uid=1000(server) gid=1000(server) groups=1000(server),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1001(testgroup)`
>
> **`ls –la`**
>    `drwxrwxr-x  21  server  testgroup  4096  Jun 23 16:36 .`
>    `drwxr-xr-x   5  root    root       4096  Jun 19 16:56 ..`
>    `drwxrwxr-x   7  server  testgroup  4096  Jun 23 16:35 folder`

Comment: Can you post the output of `groups` (and/or `id –a`) and `ls –la` commands for the `test` user?

Comment: @Scott
**id -a**

uid=1000(server) gid=1000(server) groups=1000(server),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1001(testgroup)
**ls -la**                                                                        rwxrwxr-x 21 server testgroup     4096 Jun 23 16:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root            4096 Jun 19 16:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x  7 server testgroup     4096 Jun 23 16:35 folder

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it doesn’t quite seem to match what you posted before.  I was expecting to see `/home/test` owned by `root`:“`test`” and mode 755, but you show it owned by “`server`”:“`testgroup`”, mode 775.  I was expecting to see a `/home/test/share`, owned by “`other`”; you show a subdirectory called “`folder`”, owned (also) by “`server`”.  And why, when user `test` runs `id –a`, does it says that his uid is “`server`”?

Comment: @Scott sorry about the delayed response, I was away from home for the past week. I redone all the steps again on a VM and it worked fine. But when i tried it on some older files and for some reason I get this error on WinSCP "error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp" looks like a permission problem that is only effecting older files.   
`-rwxrwxr-x  1 other testgroup        0 Jul  1 15:56 test.txt`                                                   
`-rwxrwxr-x  1 other testgroup        7 Jul  1 16:05 test.txt`